# How to set image with :before and data attribute with css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i want to set image background with :before only because on top i will put some content

previously i have used data attribute dynamically to set it with before.

**Question:** how i'm changing number with `:before` same thing i'm expecting for image

**here is what im trying:**

```
  <li data-image="https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF">hello 1</li>
  background: url(attr(data-image));
```

**below is full code:**

```js
setInterval(function(){
            var randomImages = ['https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF','https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF0000','https://via.placeholder.com/150/FFFF00'];
            var imagIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
           $('li:eq('+imagIndex+')').attr('data-image',randomImages[imagIndex]);
         // console.log(randomImages[imagIndex]);
      $('#displayingWithBefore').attr('data-number',imagIndex);
},200);
```

```css
ul{
            list-style: none;
            line-height: 43px;
        }

        li{position: relative;}

        li:before{
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 40px;
            background: url(attr(data-image));
        }

   #displayingWithBefore{
        position: relative;
        width: 90px;
        height: 90px;
        background:red;
        color: #fff;
    }

#displayingWithBefore:before {
    content: attr(data-number);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 92px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<div id="container">
       <div id="displayingWithBefore"></div>
        <ul>
            <li>hello 1</li>
            <li>hello 2</li>
            <li>hello 3</li>
        </ul>
   </div>
```

Still I'm expecting good Answer

Please help me thanks in advance!!!

Comment: i have very cleaner way of doing it with number, without javascript or jquery only with before, see my code of changing number

Comment: Yes, because with number, you are dealing with content, not background

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While there is a strong call for this from many developers, currently you cannot use attributes for URLs.

An alternative is to use CSS custom properties:

```html
<li style="--image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF);">hello 1</li>
```

```css
  /* your code … */
  li:before {
    background: var(--image);
  }
```

Browser support is good, but you might want to weigh this option, versus simply inlining the `background-image` property and using a hidden background trick on the element itself:

```html
<li style="background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF);">hello 1</li>
```

```css
  /* your code … */
  li { background-size: 0 0; }
  li:before {
    background-image: inherit;
  }
```

Comment: What if i want to add some more `style` to `style` let say background color,  right now you have   `style="--image: https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF;"`

Comment: You can red more about [CSS Custom Properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*) but you can string along other styles like you usually do. Custom properties follow the same rules others styles do. `style="--image: https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF; background-color: red;"` works just fine.

Comment: i have tried 1st method it is not working for me. please check it

Comment: Sorry about that, I have updated my answer — you'll need to make sure the inlined CSS variable has `url(...)` wrapped around it (and thus not have it in the stylesheet), and that'll work. [Working demo on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chriskirknielsen/cgj1dqy8/)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood right, and based on the way you are randomizing the `data-image` attribute every 200 ms that means you want random background every 200 ms. If so, just append the style to head using jQuery.

If not just set the `data-image` once and append the style to head.

Here in my example I followed your code, which is generating random background every 200ms.

I hope this make sense.

```js
setInterval(function(){
            var randomImages = ['https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF','https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF0000','https://via.placeholder.com/150/FFFF00'];
            var imagIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
           $('li:eq('+imagIndex+')').attr('data-image',randomImages[imagIndex]);
         // console.log(randomImages[imagIndex]);
         $('head').append('<style>li:before{background: url("'+randomImages[imagIndex]+'");}</style>');
},200);
```

```css
ul{
            list-style: none;
            line-height: 43px;
        }

        li{position: relative;}

        li:before{
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 40px;
            <!--background: url(attr(data-image)); You don't need this--> 
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<div id="container">
        <ul>
            <li>hello 1</li>
            <li>hello 2</li>
            <li>hello 3</li>
        </ul>
   </div>
```